# Android 4, how to close select panel on change event

Tags: javascript, android, webview

On Android 4 the html select elements open a panel with a "Done" button. User can pick one element and then click "Done" to close the panel. The Javascript change event occurs when the user picks one of the elements not when the Done buttons is pressed. I would like to programmatically close the panel on the change event, saving the user from having to tap the Done button.

I have tried sending focus to other elements and also doing a blur on the select element, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling "blur()" on the select-element works on my Phones:
Android-Browser 4.1.2 and 
Mobile Safari 6.0

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    this.blur();
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work neither in GT-P7500 nor in GT-P5110 (samsung galaxy tab 10.1 and samsung galaxy tab 2 10.1)